# Is the default selection of xclip the primary one?

Tags: xclip

In the manpage of `xclip`

```
-selection

specify which X selection to use, options are 
"primary" to use XA_PRIMARY (default), 
"secondary" for XA_SECONDARY or 
"clipboard" for XA_CLIPBOARD
```

Since the default one is primary selection, why doesn't clicking the mouse's middle button paste the output of `dmesg`, after running

```
    dmesg | xclip
```

Thanks.

Comment: `dmesg | xclip` works me me

Comment: clicking the middle button of my mouse doesn't paste the output of `dmesg`. when I use `xsel` with primary selection, clicking the middle button of my mouse does work i.e. pastes the output that was copied by `xsel`.

Comment: clocking the middle button of my mouse paste the output of `dmesg` for me (after running `dmesg | xclip`).

Comment: Works for me too :-)